# How to exclude header files when i search repositories in github?

Tags: github, github-api

Sorry for rookie question, I want to search a specific API in Github, but want to exclude every file match that has a .h at the end, how to do this? I set the filter to only C files, but that doesn't exclude .h files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Github Search Code API, and you want to remove a specific extension, add:

```
-extension:[your_extension]
```

Example: `-extension:h` to exclude all header files in your case

References:

- [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-code#search-by-file-extension) about the extension param
- [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#exclude-certain-results) about param exclusion

API example:

https://api.github.com/search/code?q=org:google%20language:c%20-extension:h

This also works on Github Search UI: https://github.com/search?q=org%3Agoogle+language%3Ac+-extension%3Ah